# MySql Query - Grouping records to get the percentage

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

To illustrate it in my most simplest way:

Table **User:** *(nothing special)*

```
-----------------------------------------
UserID  |        Fullname
-----------------------------------------
 User1   |        JohnDoe
-----------------------------------------
 User2   |        PeterPan
-----------------------------------------
 User3   |        BatMan
-----------------------------------------
```

Table **Group**

```
----------------------------------------
GroupID     |   Group_Name             |
----------------------------------------
      1     |   Manager                |
----------------------------------------
      2     |   Reviewer               |
----------------------------------------
```

Table **Employee**

```
----------------------------------------
UserID  |   GroupID            |
----------------------------------------
 User1  |        1             |
----------------------------------------
 User2  |        2             |
----------------------------------------
 User3  |        2             |
----------------------------------------
```

Table **Project Assignment**

```
--------------------------------------------------------
ID   | ProjectID    | Reviewer |  Status
--------------------------------------------------------
 1   |        1     | User2    | Approved
--------------------------------------------------------
 2   |        2     | User2    | Disapproved
---------------------------------------------------------
 3   |        2     | User2    | Approved
---------------------------------------------------------
 4   |        3     | User3    | Disapproved
---------------------------------------------------------
 5   |        3     | User3    | Disapproved
---------------------------------------------------------
 6   |        3     | User3    | Disapproved
---------------------------------------------------------
 7   |        3     | User3    | Approved
---------------------------------------------------------
```

**Data brief Details:**

- User2 and User3 are Reviewers
- Under **Project Assignment** table, the *Project* can be submitted more than once until the *Reviewer* set the *Status* as Approved (*See note below*)
- **> NOTE:** *There are instances where the Status can be approved twice that is why **I need to count the number of Approved project over Disapproved**.*

**Problem:**

> I want to query **Project Assignment** table to get the percentage of *Approved*(Status) Project **group by ProjectID** per Reviewer
>
> Now, what I've got is the total count of all Projects not on per Reviewer assigned Projects

**My Sql query:**

```
SELECT `Reviewer`, 
`ProjectID`,
 COUNT(*) as NumberOfTimesProjectSubmitted ,  
 Round((Select COUNT(*) From `Project Assignment` 
       Where Status='Approved') / (COUNT(*)) *100,2) AS Approval_Percentage 
FROM `Project Assignment`
GROUP by ProjectID
```

**Expected Query Result probably like this:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Reviewer | ProjectID | NumberOfTimesProjectSubmitted | Approval Percentage
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 User2   |    1      |             1                 |  100.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 User2   |    2      |             2                 |   50.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 User3   |    3      |             4                 |   25.00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*Sorry if maybe I missed some details but thats how I illustrate my problem to solve. I did try several times (almost a day already)  but coudn't get the result. I tried individual query but still get the total number of projects not per project under a Reviewer.*

Comment: Add Reviewer to the group by clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the simplest level, you just need to group by reviewer and project ID.  However, you can also remove your subqueries to get the approval percentage.

```
SELECT `Reviewer`, 
   `ProjectID`,
    COUNT(*) as NumberOfTimesProjectSubmitted ,  
    Round((SUM(CASE When Status = 'Approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*), 2)) 
    AS Approval_Percentage
FROM `Project Assignment`
GROUP by Reviewer, ProjectID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using `sum` with expression `sum(Status='Approved')` will result as a boolean 0/1 and will result as a count based on your criteria then you can make your calculations for approval percentage as `( sum(Status='Approved')  / COUNT(*)) * 100` no need for subquery

```
SELECT `Reviewer`, 
`ProjectID`,
 COUNT(*) as NumberOfTimesProjectSubmitted ,
 ( sum(Status='Approved')  / COUNT(*)) * 100 Approval_Percentage 
FROM `Project_Assignment`
GROUP by ProjectID,Reviewer
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23c14/13)